# Find command associated with configuration file

Tags: files, configuration, man, documentation

Let's say I didn't know what `~/.bashrc` is for. Is there a command that would tell me what the file is/does? Other than googling for an answer. The man pages have a files section, maybe there is a way to tell man: give me the man page for the command that has this file in its man page FILES section. Does something like this exist?

Comment: `man -K bashrc` does something like a full text search (I don't know the details). See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8982. Also http://askubuntu.com/q/116112. You can also just google for "full text search man pages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a package manager, you can query, which package owns a given file.

On Arch Linux, you can use

```
pacman -Qo FILENAME
```

On Ubuntu, Debian and other distributions with apt, you can use

```
apt-file FILENAME
```

To search man files, you can use `zgrep`

```
cd /usr/share/man
find -name *.gz | \        # List all *.gz files
while read line; do        # For each file:
  zgrep bashrc "$line" &&  # call zgrep with pattern and filename
  echo "--- $line ---";    # print filename if zgrep found something (&&)
done                       #
```

Comment: That won't work for most configuration files in the user's home directory, because they don't come in any package. `.bashrc` is one of the few for which this might work, because many distributions package an `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, because it's probably what you should try first in this situation. If the package manager yielded no results, then move on to `grep` or `man -K` as Gilles answer suggests.

Comment: Also, `apt-file` is not installed by default (at least on mint). `dpkg -S .bashrc` can be used without installing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Google is often the quickest way. However, if you want to search man pages, you can use the following to list (`-w`) all man pages of user commands (section 1) containing the text `.bashrc` anywhere:

```
man -w -s 1 -K .bashrc
```

For a file like `.bashrc`, this will turn up a few false positives in the form of man pages that suggest adding an alias or other setting to `.bashrc`. This command is for the man-db implementation of man, which is popular under Linux. There are other man implementations that don't have an option for full-text search; you can use `grep` instead after finding out where the man pages are located, e.g.

```
grep -F .bashrc /usr/man/man1/*.1
```

If you want to find which program accesses that configuration file, you can set up a monitoring system. You can use [LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) to monitor all accesses in a directory tree. Monitoring your whole home directory is likely to be extremely verbose, and LoggedFS can only monitor a directory tree, not a regular file by itself, so to monitor a specific file, move it to a directory of its own and create a symbolic link.

```
mkdir ~/monitored
mv ~/.bashrc ~/monitored
ln -s monitored/.bashrc ~
loggedfs -l ~/monitored.log ~/monitored
```

Watch the log file to see when a process accesses it. By default, the process name is included in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend @akrafs answer, but if that is not detailed enough; you can set up auditd to log which file accessed the configuration file.

More details in : http://www.la-samhna.de/library/audit.html

Comment: Inotify only lets you know when a file is accessed, not which program accessed it.

Comment: Thnx, you are right; inotify does not tell you the name of the process that accessed the file.